# First member of struct not visible in VS debugger

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, masm, visual-studio-debugging

I am a new bee of assembly language. When i am learning to write a struct, strange things happened.

This is the struct i define

```
User struct 
    name byte 20 dup(0)
    password byte 10 dup(0)
    more byte "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
User ends
```

this is how i declare a variable

`user1 User <"chi","fan">`

but when i inspect variable user1 in visual studio 2019,
i cant see the first member of struct name

close inspect window: [image: close inspect window]

Memory window: [image: memory window]

my full code of data.asm

```
Employee struct
    IdNum byte "000000000"              ; 9
    LastName byte 30 DUP(0)             ; 30
    ALIGN word                          ; 
    Years word 0                        ; 2
    ALIGN dword                         ; 
    SalaryHistory dword 0,0,0,0         ; 16
Employee ends     


Employee2 struct
    IdNum byte "000000000"              ; 9
    LastName byte 30 DUP(0)             ; 30
    ALIGN word                          ; 
    Years word 0                        ; 2
    ALIGN dword                         ; 
    SalaryHistory dword 0,0,0,0         ; 16
Employee2 ends    


User struct 
    name byte 20 dup(0)
    password byte 10 dup(0)
    more byte "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
User ends

user1 User <"chi","fan">
worker4 Employee <"888","555">
worker2 Employee2 <"aaa","bbb">
```

my full code in main.asm

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data
    include data.asm
.code
main PROC
  mov worker4.SalaryHistory, 1000H        ;
                                          ; 

  invoke ExitProcess,0
main ENDP
END main
```

environment: windows,visual studio 2019

Comment: There's something funny about field `name` -- change it to `aname` and it will work, but I don't know why..  In a listing file, you can see that it simply skips over the `name byte 20 dup(0)` giving it no storage, no matter where it is in the struct, but gives storage to `aname byte 20 dup(0)`.  Does anybody know what makes `name` special?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**: In modern versions of MASM (including the versions in Visual Studio) a line beginning with `name` is effectively ignored.

---

`NAME` is a [reserved word](https://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/coe/mudawar/coe205/manuals/MASMProgrGuide/D-ReservedWords.pdf) in MASM. Versions of MASM in Visual Studio process the [`NAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/name-masm?view=vs-2019) directive as taking a string, but these modern versions of MASM ignore the results of the directive. `NAME` is a directive that exists to allow better source compatibility with earlier versions of MASM.

Because of this a line that starts with `NAME` like:

```
name byte 20 dup(0)
```

is essentially ignored. This is why it doesn't appear in the debugger, nor can you reference it with something like:

```
mov user1.name, 'c'
```

The result of this should be that `name` is an undefined symbol.

---

Solutions:

- rename the `name` member to something like `uname` or any other name that isn't a MASM reserved word.
- Use the [`NOKEYWORD`](https://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/coe/mudawar/coe205/manuals/MASMProgrGuide/D-ReservedWords.pdf) option to tell MASM that you want to override `name` as a reserved word. Add this to the top of `data.asm` (or `main.asm`)

  ```
  OPTION NOKEYWORD:<NAME>
  ```

  This tells MASM not to consider `NAME` as a reserved word. This should prevent the unwanted behaviour of MASM ignoring an entire line that starts with `NAME`.

Comment: A listing file suggests that MASM is the culprit rather than the debugger: the entire line is ignored, no storage is given to that line of declaration.  In other words, things are already wrong 
 (not what is desired/expected) before even running the debugger.

Comment: Additional info: The [`NAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/name-masm?view=vs-2019) statement/directive is ignored.  It was originally used to specify that the file being assembled was an application (rather than a DLL), and optionally included an app name and/or app type.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm : I was doing investigation and when I returned I saw your comment. That is actually my assessment as well. I had updated my answer before I notice the comment, but you are quite correct. The result is that any line starting with `name` is essentially ignored which is why this code specifically appears to ignore the line altogether. By using NOKEYWORD as my original answer suggested removes this behavior.

Comment: I had to pull out an old MASM manual from ~1992 to look up the details on NAME.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm : funny the first reference I found that stood out when I did a google query was Intel's MCS-86 documentation from the late 70s. (and then something similar in TASM's ideal mode)